# Is there a word like "likeness" referring to a person's appearance, but their voice instead?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, technical

AI is topical at the moment, with some actors' likenesses being used as training data for some purpose or another. "Likeness", however, has the connotation of being about appearances, i.e. your physical features.

But it's also a hot topic in the voice acting community, where VAs could lend their voice to training data. If "likeness" is about appearance, is there a similar word but for voices? "Soundness"?

For example, in the sentences:

"They used his likeness to train the model."

"They used his soundness to train the model."

Comment: ]Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vocalization#:~:text=vocalization%20(countable%20and%20uncountable%2C%20plural,voice%2C%20especially%20as%20an%20exercise)) arguably includes this sense for 'vocalisation' ['Any specific mode of utterance; pronunciation'], but it's by no means the default sense.

Comment: his speaking style

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use the term **vocals** or **voice**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocal) defines the adjective *vocal* as (among other meanings) *of, related to, or resembling the voice*, and the noun as *a vocal sound*. While *vocals* (as a noun) is often used to refer to the sung part of a musical composition or performance, I have seen **vocals** or similar constructions used to refer to one's *vocal likeness*:

> Activision sent us a mailer announcing that Garbage's Shirley Manson has lent her likeness and **vocal stylings** to Guitar Hero 5. (Stephany Nunneley-Jackson, "[Shirley Manson adding likeness and **vocals** to Guitar Hero 5](https://www.vg247.com/shirley-manson-adding-likeness-and-vocals-to-guitar-hero-5)", VG247, 29 July 2009.

> Dolly Parton Not Keen to Have AI Use Her **Vocals** or Create Her Likeness After Her Death ([AceShowbiz](https://www.aceshowbiz.com/news/view/00207856.html), 2 July 2023)

> Part of what has etched Ogg into our minds is lending his **vocals** and likeness to the villainous (but loveable) Trevor in 2013's GTA V. (Tom Chapman, "[GTA V Actor Sends Angry Video Message To GTA 6 Fan](https://www.ggrecon.com/articles/gta-v-actor-sends-angry-video-message-to-gta-6-fan/)," GGRecon, 7 October 2022)

> The vocals of these characters are done by the following actors. (Huzaifa Malik, "[Forspoken: All Voice Actors and Cast.](https://exputer.com/guides/forspoken-voice-actors-cast/)" *Exputer*, 26 January 2023.)

In a legal context, a related word used for giving permission is **voice** itself. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voice) documents that use generally (*sound so produced by human beings*), but some usages appear in juxtaposition with one's *likeness* or *image*:

> Authorization for use of Image, **Voice**, and/or Likeness ([Stanislaus State](https://www.csustan.edu/communications/authorization-for-use-of-image-voice-likeness))

> Release and authorization to use **voice** or likeness & guide [...] The party that will use the **voice** or likeness is called the “Company” and the party giving the release and authorization to use his or her image is called the “Releasor.” ([Legal Zoom](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/release-and-authorization-to-use-voice-or-likeness-guide))

> Release for Use of Name, Likeness, **Voice**, Image or Performance and Copyright License ([University of New Mexico Clinical Translational Science Center](https://hsc.unm.edu/research/brep/common/docs/mscr/mscr-permission-presenter.pdf))

> A right of publicity is the right to control the commercial value of your name, likeness, **voice**, signature, or other personal identifying traits that are unique to you. ([Higgs | Fletcher | Mack](https://higgslaw.com/celebrities-sue-over-unauthorized-use-of-identity/))

Comment: "Vocals" is often a technical term used in the recording industry, so I'd use "voice" unless you really know what you're talking about and are being very specific. Like if we talk about Dolly Parton's vocals, we're probably talking about her musical performances rather than, say, a recording of a speech she made.

Comment: *"The voice of his master"* - RCA.

Answer (score 7):

You could use ***timbre***:

> a quality of sound that makes voices or musical instruments sound different from each other:
>
> - He has a wonderful singing voice, with a rich ***timbre*** and resonant tone. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/timbre))

Comment: To my mind, the [***timbre** of his voice*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22timbre+of+his+voice%22) is primarily about the ***harmonics*** (which the speaker normally has little control over), whereas the [***tonality** of his voice*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tonality+of+his+voice%22) also includes ***intonation, inflection, cadence*** (usually under the speaker's conscious control). But I'm not sure if everyone else would agree that distinction, nor is it obvious to me which exact sense OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I like ***cadence*** in this scenario

> a modulation or inflection of the voice.
>
> - "his measured cadences never convey the character's underlying passion"

Comment: You should include the source of the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Likeness means resemblance. You do not train an AI model on images that *resemble* someone, you train the model on images *of* someone. You would say:

"They used images of him to train the model."

So for sound,

"They used recordings of him to train the model."

--

However, if all you want is a word that refers to the specific quality of a person's voice, you could use "**dulcet tones**."

> dulcet tones
> (phrase)
> People often use the expression dulcet tones to refer to someone's voice.
> [humorous]
> -- Collins Dictionary

"They used his dulcet tones to train the model."

Or less colloquially, "**speech**".

> an individual manner or style of speaking -- Merriam-Webster

"They used his speech to train the model."